# Can't checkout SVN repository; Server doesn't receive request

Tags: vps, svn, timeout

I have a VPS. From this VPS, I'm trying to checkout a repository at `svn://svn.server.dom/repos`. Some time after, I receive a timeout message.

If I run `ping svn.server.dom`, it works fine.

Here's the thing though: the server is not even receiving the svn request. I talked to the network admin, and the server receives the ping command with no issues (I also receive the server response), but the svn request doesn't even show up in the log. So I would guess that my VPS can't reach the server, but then the ping shouldn't work either!

Trying to checkout from other machines works fine. I'm running CentOS 6 and SVN 1.8.1 on the VPS.

What can possibly be happening?

Comment: Check the involved firewalls and play with tcpdump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a TCP connection on port 3690 - I bet it's filtered in a firewall in front of your server instead of being open to the world.

```
nc -v svn.server.dom 3690
```

You could allow that in your firewall, but ***don't*** - the `svn://` protocol is completely insecure, all data including your authentication data is passing over the internet in plaintext.

Instead, set up your SVN server to serve the repo over `https://` with WebDAV or `svn+ssh://`.

Comment: I didn't realize svn was *that* insecure. We usually use this SVN only internally, I never thouhg about it. Well, time to make a case for git. :)